# I need to update two tables in one SQL Query

Tags: sqlite

In python I have the following code:

```
cursor.execute("""
UPDATE customerDetails
SET customerDetails.cust_owed =
(customerDetails.cust_owed -orders.order_price),                                     
customerDetails.cust_paid = orders.order_price
WHERE orders.orderID = ?
AND orders.customerID = customerDetails.customerID""", (orderID,))
```

However it doesn't work, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just do two updates in a single transaction.

Comment: @Shawn, there are at least 5 major problems with his SQL. I think he needs a little more direction...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two separate sub selections to make this work.

Also, you need to remove the table name from the column names you are updating.

```
UPDATE customerDetails
SET    cust_owed = (cust_owed - (SELECT order_price FROM orders WHERE orders.orderID = ?)),
       cust_paid = (SELECT order_price FROM orders WHERE orders.orderID = ?)
WHERE customerID = (
    SELECT customerID FROM orders WHERE orderID = ? )


cursor.execute("""
  UPDATE customerDetails
  SET    cust_owed = (cust_owed - (SELECT order_price FROM orders WHERE orders.orderID = ?)),
         cust_paid = (SELECT order_price FROM orders WHERE orders.orderID = ?)
  WHERE customerID = (
      SELECT customerID FROM orders WHERE orderID = ? )""", (orderID,orderID,orderID))
```

Answer (score -1):

As I know you can separate every SQL Query by semicolon (;) .
For example:

```
Cursor.execute("""Update table 
(id,name) values ('1','test') where 
id=1;Update table (id,name) values 
('2','test2') where id=2;""")
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: If you had read the actual query, you would have realized he actually wants to update two columns utilizing two tables.  Not actually update two tables.  This answer does not address his question